# Unable to read edited data in extjs Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am new in ext js and wanted to do some POC for Grid.
I need to read the data from oracle database and click on editor updater and then get that updated that and then pass it to a servlet for editing.

I did till rendering data from Database but now unable to prodeed as not getting how to get updated data and pass it to servlet.

Please find my code for Grid -

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.util.*',
    'Ext.state.*'
]);

// Define Person entity
// Null out built in convert functions for performance *because the raw data 


  Ext.onReady(function() {


Ext.QuickTips.init();

// setup the state provider, all state information will be saved to a cookie
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));


    Ext.define('person', {
                extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                fields: [


                    {name: 'sso', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'fname', type: 'string'},

                    {name: 'lname', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'msso', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'email_address', type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'person_status', type: 'string'}                     
                ]
            });

 var ds = new Ext.data.Store({
            model:'person',
              autoLoad: true, 
            //url:'/FormAction',
             actionMethods: {create: "POST", read: "POST", update:          "POST", destroy: "POST"},
         proxy: {  
             type: 'ajax',      
             url: '/identityiq/FormAction',       
             reader: {      
                 type: 'xml',
                 record: 'record'
              },
           }                

            });

var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                clicksToEdit: 1
            });

   // create the Grid
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: ds,
    columns: [
        {
            text     : 'SSO',
            width:80,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'sso'
        },
        {
                    id: 'fname',
                    header: 'First Name',
                    dataIndex: 'fname',
                    width:80,
                    flex: 1,
                    field: {
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
        },
        {

            id: 'lname',
            header     : 'Last Name',
            width:80,               
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'lname',
            field: {
                        allowBlank: false
                    }
        },
        {
            text     : 'Manager SSO',
            width    : 80,
            sortable : true,               
            dataIndex: 'msso'
        },
        {
            text     : 'Email Address',
            width    : 80,
            sortable : true,               
            dataIndex: 'email_address'
        },
        {
            text     : 'Personstatus',
            width    : 35,
            sortable : true,               
            dataIndex: 'person_status'
        }
    ],
    selModel: {
        selType: 'cellmodel'
    },
    height: 350,
    width: 600,
    title: 'Array Grid',
    renderTo: 'myDiv',
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true,
        enableTextSelection: true
    },
    frame: true,
    tbar: [
 {
     text: 'Save',


     handler: function ()
     {
        // myGrid is a reference to your Ext.grid.Panel instance
        if (grid.editingPlugin.editing) {


            var value = grid.editingPlugin.getActiveEditor().field.value;

            alert('Value: ' + value);
        }
     }
 }
 ],
    plugins: [cellEditing]
});
});
```

-- in this code i am getting error that 
TypeError: grid.editingPlugin.getActiveEditor(...) is null

Request you to please answer this as i am stuck and need to present this POC.

Thanks,
Ashwini

As per the answer below following code is working fine if i replace the save Handler -

```
    handler: function ()
     {
        alert(ds.getModifiedRecords());
        console.log(ds.getModifiedRecords());

        var modified_data ={};
        modified_data = ds.getModifiedRecords();

        for (var i = 0; i < modified_data.length; i++) {
    var record =          modified_data[i];                 
                alert(record.data.fname);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that problem with your `Save` button handler is that you are trying to get active editor for a cell, but cell editor is automatically removed once it loses focus so `grid.editingPlugin.getActiveEditor()` return `null`.

Good thing is that you don't have to do this, `Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing` automatically updates appropriate store record for you, so all you have to do to get all modifications inside your `Save` button handler is this:

```
// Simply use your store method for fetching modified records
console.log(ds.getModifiedRecords());
```

If you need to do something after cell is edited, then you should check out [Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing edit event](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-edit).

Comment: Thanks alot it works. But again Just have one question in mind. Can I pass the modified record array to my processing servlet in order to avoid to give ajax request for each of the single record? If i get the code Snippet for that then it will be fine. Thanks Again For the valuable comment. I will update the code above so that can be useful to others.

Comment: @user3224915 If I understand your question right then maybe you should take a look at [Ext.JSON.encode](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.JSON-method-encode) method. Just encode array of modified data you need, pass that as parameter to ajax request and decode what you get on server side.

Comment: @user3224915 Maybe you should also read [MVC Architecture](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/application_architecture) document page. Pay special attention to `Saving to the server` section.

Answer (score 0):

Try using grid's SelectionModel to get the data, something like

```
var valueList = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection(); //Returns an array of the currently selected records.
var value =  valueList[0].data.fname; //Should get First Name
```

Comment: Thanks alot it is also working fine. But again Just have one question in mind as i asked above as well. Can I pass the modified record array to my processing servlet in order to avoid to give ajax request for each of the single record? If i get the code Snippet for that then it will be fine. Thanks Again For the valuable comment. I will update the code above so that can be useful to others.